# AndroidStudio build.gradle Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android Studio 1.4
Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties config:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental), according to it, one of the difference of the experimental plugin is:

> Plugin name is com.android.model.application instead of com.android.application.  Or use apply plugin: "com.android.model.library" if you want to create an Android aar library.

But according to your error, you've tried to apply it with the wrong plugin name.

Comment: I've tried apply plugin: "com.android.model.library",it does not recognize.

Comment: @TeSheng if so, then provide pleas your project structure and full build.gradle files contents

Comment: The build.gradle files of Library:
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'


model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        }
    }
}

Comment: The build.gradle of project:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: The gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

@Stanislav I have solved the question. The library build.gradle automatic generation 'TestCompile' method and prone to bugs.